# Testing for custom error reverts in hardhat

Tags: testing, hardhat, waffle, custom-errors

I have a custom error described as such:

```js
error AlreadyListed(address nftAddress, uint256 tokenId);
```

And in my tests, I'd like to check to see that it's thrown:

```
expect(await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)).to.be.revertedWith(`AlreadyListed`)
```

However, this of course fails with:

```
 Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with custom error 'AlreadyListed("0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512", 0)
```

Do I need to string interpolate with quotes and such, or is there a better way? This looks ugly:

```js
expect(await nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)).to.be.revertedWith(`AlreadyListed("${basicNft.address}", ${TOKEN_ID})`)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try moving the `await` *before* the `expect`. e.g.

```js
await expect(nftMarketplace.listItem(basicNft.address, TOKEN_ID, PRICE)).to.be.revertedWith(`AlreadyListed`)
```

That's what my tests use for custom errors

Hope this helps

Comment: this worked. any idea why it didn't worked when written "await" inside bracket?

Comment: Anything inside the parenthesis will be fully executed _before_ being passed into expect(). Thus, if awaiting the call will fail, expect() will never even be called to check.

Instead, we just pass in the Promise<> to expect() and await for expect() to decide what to do -- which it is fully capable of catching and comparing Promise<> errors when used with .to.be.revertedWith()

Answer (score 22):

Update to selected answer

## Custom error

*hardhat will check for the name of the error, not the contents of the message*

**MyContract.sol**

```csharp
error SomeCustomError(string message);

contract MyContract {
    function someFunction() public {

        if (!false) {
            revert SomeCustomError("Some error message");
        }
    }
}
```

**MyContract.ts**

```js
await expect(contract.call()).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(
  contract,
  "SomeCustomError"
);
```

got from hardhat docs
https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/overview

### Basic Revert

**MyContract.sol**

```csharp
contract MyContract {

    function someFunction() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 1 ether, "Please send enough ETH");
    }
}
```

**MyContract.ts**

```js
await expect(contract.someFunction()).to.be.revertedWith("Some error message");
```

Answer (score 0):

Current hardhat documentation:

```
await expect(contract.call()).to.be.reverted;
```

or revert and test the error message:

```
await expect(contract.call()).to.be.revertedWith("Some revert message");
```

Example:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Storage Contract Test", function () {
    let owner;

    beforeEach(async function() {
        [owner] = await ethers.getSigners();

        const SimpleStorage = await ethers
            .getContractFactory("SimpleStorage");

        simpleStorage = await SimpleStorage.deploy();
    });

    
it("should not set a new contract owner to the zero address", async () => {
        //Arrange
        const zeroAddr = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        //Act
        const currentAddr = await simpleStorage.getOwner();
        //Assert
        expect(currentAddr).to.equal(owner.address);
        console.log(currentAddr);
        await expect(simpleStorage.changeOwner(zeroAddr))
            .to.be.reverted;
        await expect(simpleStorage.changeOwner(zeroAddr))
            .to.be.revertedWith("new owner cannot be zero address 0x0")
    });
});
```