# Test fails with custom error despite having "MyCustomError"

Tags: solidity, hardhat, custom-errors

I'm writing a test that requires enterRaffle() to be reverted with MyCustomError - "Raffle__NotEnoughEthEntered"

```
describe("enterRaffle", async function () {
              it("reverts when you don't pay enough", async function () {
                  await expect(raffle.enterRaffle()).to.be.revertedWith(
                      "Raffle__NotEnoughEthEntered"
                  )
              })
          })
```

The test fails with error;

```shell
1) Raffle
       enterRaffle
         reverts when you don't pay enough:
     AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted with reason 'Raffle__NotEnoughEthEntered', but it reverted with a custom error
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/unit/Raffle.test.js:32:19)
```

Why is Raffle__NotEnoughEthEntered not a custom error?

I have read other [similar issues](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/123391/testing-for-custom-error-reverts-in-hardhat) but they don't solve my problem.

###### Raffle.sol `error` & `enterRaffle`

```
error Raffle__NotEnoughEthEntered();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function enterRaffle() public payable {
        // you can do this,
        //require (msg.value > i_enteranceFee, "Not Enough ETH!")

        // but we will use error codes for gas efficiency since storing strings if supper expensive
        if (msg.value < i_enteranceFee) {
            revert Raffle__NotEnoughEthEntered();
        }

        if (s_raffleState != RaffleState.OPEN) {
            revert Raffle__NotOpen();
        }
        s_players.push(payable(msg.sender));

        //Emit an event when we update a dynamic array or mapping
        //name events with fuction name reversed. in this case event RaffleEnter()
        emit RaffleEnter(msg.sender);
    }
```

Comment: Reference (https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/overview) for more about reverts with examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as far as I know `to.be.revertedWith` is used for catching string errors.
To expect a Custom Error you need to use `to.be.revertedWithCustomError(contractInstance,NameOfTheCustomError)`. Also if the custom error have args you can add `.withArgs(..args)`.

You can check an example for the use in the [lsp-smart-contract](https://github.com/lukso-network/lsp-smart-contracts/blob/82e27720a98a2bc7e1c00f8d686abfa7d1942de3/tests/LSP6KeyManager/tests/PermissionCall.test.ts#L117) repo.

Check the hardhat config file to see which package to use. I assume it's `@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox`.

Comment: Thanks! @Yamen
Super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and found that using rejectedWith("MyCustomError") instead of revertedWith("MyCustomError") resolved the problem. While I haven't identified the specific distinction between revertedWith and rejectedWith, the latter proved to be effective in my case.